# Host a registered domain website on your own server

Tags: networking, web-hosting, self-hosting

I have a registered domain and i need to use my own server to host my website, I have [understood the risks](https://superuser.com/questions/377815/host-your-own-website-and-dns-server) of hosting my own site but anyways want to pursue this , so how to bind our registered domain to our own host server?

Answer (score 1):

You can use host your DNS on a website such as [Afraid.org](http://www.afraid.org/) and set it to point to your home IP.

To do this, make an account on Afraid, go to your registrar and set your nameservers to the ones mentioned on Afraid.

Then, on Afraid, add a new A entry for your domain/subdomain to make it point to your IP address (or CNAME entry if you want to point to a different hostname).

If you've had experiences with other free DNS hosting services please share, I only tried Afraid and I didn't feel a need to use a different one.

Comment: thanks, also what if we want to register domain name on our own , how to do it?

Comment: It has to be through a registrar. You do not have the authority to register domains on public DNS. You could create your own DNS and add your own domain there, but only people using your DNS can see that domain. The DNS (Domain Name Server) is a server that translates an address like "google.com" to an ip like "216.58.209.206",

Answer (score 0):

Consult your domain registrar for instructions on how to modify your DNS entries to point your domain name to your own server IP.

Comment: Note in addition, your ISP must not block port 80.

Comment: Beat me to it.  You may want to check to see if you have a static (doesn't change) or dynamic (changes every X hours) IP address.  If you have a static, you're good to go.  If you have a dynamic, you'll have to deal with updating your registrar with your new IP address every time it changes.

Comment: Also note that if you are using ADSL, the performance will be limited, as the _down-load_ speed for visitors to your site will be your _up-load_ speed.

Answer (score 0):

It will be significantly less stressful to use a VPS from DigitalOcean, Linode or Amazon.  A $5/month "droplet" is a good place to start.  There are a ton of guides out there on setting up the web server, then you need to make DNS changes to point www.yourdomain.com to that web server.

https://www.google.com/search?q=digitalocean+setting+up+a+webserver

It's too big of a question to get into how to setup the web server, or make the DNS changes.  If you start going and have issues, come back and search in superuser, unix or askubuntu on stackexchange.  Whatever questions you have, they've been asked before ;-)